# How to build project automatically in jenkins when there is push to gerrit

Tags: git, jenkins-plugins, gerrit

please tell me in simple steps with snapshots how to set up gerrit build in jenkins...
can two repos be given to set up for gerrit build in one job in jenkins...
when the code is pushed to gerrit the build should trigger automatically on jenkins...

Comment: https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Gerrit+Trigger

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to a Jenkins job that performs build of 2 2 Repos. Still the code review have to be done on the specific change in gerrit of the specific repo.

The [Jenkins-Gerrit](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Gerrit+Trigger) plugin page gives all the info you need + Screen shots of the steps

if you want to have 1 job synching more than 1 repo than you can use the [Multiple SCMs Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Multiple+SCMs+Plugin).

Here is are 2 very nice articles about Jenkins and Gerrit configuration

1. http://alblue.bandlem.com/2011/02/gerrit-git-review-with-jenkins-ci.html
2. http://dachary.org/?p=1716

Enjoy,

Doron